# SwiftUI 2 clear background for list section header

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list, ios14

SwiftUI 2 broke a part of my app that relied on a clear background for a List section header. Previously I relied on this line to make the list sections clear. Does anyone know how to accomplish this in SwiftUI 2?

```
UITableViewHeaderFooterView.appearance().tintColor = .clear
```

Here is a sample that would work in SwiftUI 1:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(header:
                Text("List Header")
            ) {
                Text("Hi")
            }
            .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
        }
        .onAppear {
            UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            UITableViewHeaderFooterView.appearance().tintColor = .clear
        }
    }
}
```

Desired: `List Header` should be transparent and not grey.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This might help you: [Clear background for form sections in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63945992/clear-background-for-form-sections-in-swiftui)

Comment: I tried that solution, and unfortunately no luck on lists :(

Comment: It *does* work, I've just checked (unless we're talking about different things) - please add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also note you need to change the `UITableViewCell.appearance()`.

Comment: Example added. Unfortunately no luck with that solution in Xcode 12/Swiftui 2

Comment: It wasn't clear you were talking about the list *header* - I added a possible workaround for non-clear colours. But when using the default list style you probably shouldn't use the clear colour anyway (because of text-overlapping).

Comment: Hi! Please Try This -> https://youtu.be/kXt8g0v0FEI

Comment: Make Rounded Sections & your headers will be transparent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution found! The trick is to use a LazyVStack with pinned sections:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack(pinnedViews:[.sectionHeaders]) {
                Section(header: Text("List Header")) {
                    Text("Hi")
                    Text("Hi")
                    Text("Hi")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the following code will give you an empty header with the same background colour as the system if you want to add a text to it you can replace `Rectangle` by `Text("Your header")` or even use a `Stack` View

```
List {
                
                Section(header:
                            Rectangle()
                            .foregroundColor(.clear)
                            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
                            .background(Color(.systemBackground))){
         
                        //content of the list
                        Text("Item x")
                        //...

               }

      }
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem is I have an image under the list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible workaround (does not work with the *clear* color though):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(header: header) {
                Text("Item 1")
                Text("Item 2")
                Text("Item 3")
            }
            Section(header: header) {
                Text("Item 1")
                Text("Item 2")
                Text("Item 3")
            }
        }
    }

    var header: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Header")
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(5)
        .background(Color.blue)
        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
    }
}
```