# SwiftUI Change Form Background

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I currently have the following Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    
    @State var selectedDate = Date()
    @State var Placeholder = ""
    @State var isButtonPressed: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            
            DatePicker(selection: $selectedDate) {
                Text("Date")
            }
            
            TextField("Enter Text", text: $Placeholder)
            
            Section {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                
                    Button(action: {
                        self.isButtonPressed.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Save")
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }.background(Color.red)
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}
```

Which gives me this:

[Normal Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6ADA.png)

However I want to change the background of the Fields inside the Form.

I tried to use

```
.background(Color.red)
```

But it didn't change the background.

I could create a ScrollView with a VStack and then add some .clip modifiers together with a ZStack, but this is not a nice and clean solution.

So does anyone know how to only change the Background of the Fields in the Form?

Comment: `.background(Color.red)` should be working. Can you update your code to show where you called `.background(Color.red)`?

Comment: I added the code line. I placed it after the form.

Comment: This might help you: [Clear background for form sections in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63945992/clear-background-for-form-sections-in-swiftui)

Comment: Thank You. It worked. I had worked with the .clear from UIKit before but I didn't clear the Cell view, just the table view. You can write it as answer it you want

Comment: @Kataran There's no need to *duplicate* questions. Feel free to upvote the other answer if it helped you.