# Remove background of a cell in Forms - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

How do I change only the background of the yellow button so it doesn't have that white background coming from the form?

Here's what I have:

```
NavigationView {
    Form {
        Section(header: Text("Display"),
                footer: Text("System settings ...")) {
            
            Toggle(isOn: .constant(true),
                   label: {
                    Text("Dark Mode")
                   })
        }
        
        Section {
            Label("Follow me ...", systemImage: "link")
        }
        
        Section {
            Button(action: {
                
            }) {
                Text("Unlock PRO")
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                
            }) {
                Text("Restore purchase")
            }
        }
        
        Section {
            Button(action: {
                authSessionManager.signOut()
            }) {
                Text("Sign Out!")
                    .font(.footnote)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .padding()
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 40)
                    .background(Color.orange)
                    .cornerRadius(15.0)
            }
            .padding(.top)
        }
        .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
    }
    
    .navigationTitle("Settings")
}
```

this is how it looks:

[image]

And this is what I've tried:

```
.listRowBackground(Color.clear)
```

I put that at the end but makes not difference. Any idea?

NOTE: I'm not trying to remove the background of all cells like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63945992/clear-background-for-form-sections-in-swiftui), I just need 1.

I would prefer a SwiftUI native solution if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out, all I had to do was add at the end of a stack the following:

```
.listRowBackground(Color(UIColor.systemGroupedBackground))
```

Comment: Also, do not forget to add `.listRowSeparator(Visibility.hidden)` to the Section to remove the partition lines on iPods and other devices with smaller screen sizes. (Tweeted earlier: https://twitter.com/ram__patra/status/1541443305602416640?s=20&t=ddenCRtSqlcJQ2hFPqUUIA)